# Android Studio can't find existing resource

Tags: android, android-studio

Since Google recently announced that Android Studio is the official IDE for Android developement I decided to change my work environment from the Eclipse IDE to Android Studio.

After importing the project to Android Studio I've come across a strange error. 
The error says that it can't find two existing R.drawables in an array of R.drawables, the resources are two png pictures.

Here is the syntax of the array:

```
flag = new int[] {R.drawable.thegodfather,R.drawable.thegeneral,R.drawable.kingofcomedy,
 R.drawable.drstrangelove,R.drawable.thebiglebowski}
```

The two R.drawables that is causing the error are thegodfather and kingofcomedy.

Here is the error messages: 
(1)

```
>     Error:(101, 32) error: cannot find symbol variable thegodfather
>     Error:(101, 78) error: cannot find symbol variable kingofcomedy
>     Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>     Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>     > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

(2)

```
/Users/rawandsultani/Documents/ANDROID/V1/v11/app/src/main/java/com/exple/top100/Top100Activity.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
            flag = new int[] {R.drawable.thegodfather,R.drawable.thegeneral,R.drawable.kingofcomedy,
                                        ^
  symbol:   variable thegodfather
  location: class drawable
/Users/rawandsultani/Documents/ANDROID/V1/v11/app/src/main/java/com/exple/top100/Top100Activity.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
            flag = new int[] {R.drawable.thegodfather,R.drawable.thegeneral,R.drawable.kingofcomedy,
                                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable kingofcomedy
  location: class drawable
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

After countless efforts of cleansings, rebuildings, invertings and restarts the same error still exists. I have checked that the resource is actually there and I have deleted and replaced it just to be sure. It still doesn't work.

What is causing Android Studio to ignore theese two resources?

Here is the beginning of my Android-manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exple.v1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
```

And here is my Gradle.build :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.exple.v1"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

Again, I have no clue what is causing this problem. After searching on Stack I've found out that some have had a similiar problem but solved it by cleaning the project or restarting Android Studio which has not worked out for me.

The manifest file and the Gradle.build is for extra information 
just in case anyone need a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verify the do exist in the appropiate folder with the correct name in the Android project?

**EDIT:**

Have you tried to remove them (Delete) and add them from Android Studio instead of the imported version?

Comment: Yes I have verified, they both exist.

Comment: Can you describe exactly how to do that so we can avoid potential misunderstandings?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an existing resource in an imported project from eclipse. In my case the issue was that the resource called *loading.png* was in fact a *.gif*, after I fixed the extension the compiler generate the right `R.drawable.loading` variable.

When Android Studio imported the project it showed this message, but i didnt appear in the sub-sequence compilations

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT out(251470765) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT err(251470765): libpng error: Not a PNG file
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old ( very old ) topic, but I just had the same problem and I soon realized that I had placed the resource in a wrong folder ( drawable-v24 instead of drawable ) which was the reason for this resource to be found on other devices. Switch to project instead of android view and check variant specific folders.